# React - How to return HTML elements in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a JSON file that contains HTML elements in a string - Is it possible to return the data in React/JSX as valid rendered HTML?

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var exampleJSONData = {
        "item": "Hello",
        "text": "<p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>dolor sit amet</p>"
    }
    return <div>{data.item} {data.text}</div>;
  }
});
```

Returns : `Hello <p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>dolor sit amet</p>` instead of:

```
Hello
Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7jabzxvy/1/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) like this

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: data.text} } />
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/7jabzxvy/3/)

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about this dangerouslySetInnerHTML